# why does amazon-cloudwatch-agent send prometheus metrics to log groups?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Using the cloudwatch-agent, I can send log files as well as metrics to Amazon cloudwatch. For example I can send metrics for memory usage like this in my config:

```
{
  (...)
  "metrics": {
    "metrics_collected": {
      "mem": {
        "measurement": ["mem_used_percent"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now since some time cloudwatch agent has the feature of sending prometheus metrics to cloudwatch (see [here](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/containers/using-prometheus-metrics-in-amazon-cloudwatch/)).

But I have to put the configuration into the `"logs"` section of the cloudwatch agent configuration. And the metrics are (also) send to cloudwatch.

Now I wonder why?
Why can I not send the metrics directly to Cloudwatch Matrics, without Cloudwatch logs?
Is there a technical reason? Is there a reason, why this makes sense and I am just not seeing it?

Comment: Just guessing, but if you skip the CW Logs like this `agent ---> CW Metrics`, there is no way to have it as logs right. But if you include the logs like this `agent ---> CW Logs ---> CW Metrics`, then it adds flexibility for consumers. Some would want to pipe the logs to their own monitoring system.